# OrientDB query works on Studio but not with PyOrient

Tags: orientdb, pyorient

This works on OrientDB Studio (`eset` is an embeddedSet):

```
UPDATE #37:0 SET eset = eset || ["foo", "bar"];
```

But not when I use PyOrient:

```
command = 'UPDATE #37:0 SET eset = eset || ["foo", "bar"];'
client.command(command)

>>> pyorient.exceptions.PyOrientSQLParsingException: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandSQLParsingException - Error on parsing command: Invalid keyword ||.
```

Apparently it also happens with Java: https://community.orientdb.org/t/linkset-manipulation/171

Is there any way I could rewrite that query to get rid of the `||` part? I can't make heads or tails of the [documentation](https://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Update.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyOrient still uses the legacy SQL executor, that does not support `||` operator.
I'd suggest to use the following (not completely equivalent, but it should work)

```
UPDATE #37:0 ADD eset = ["foo", "bar"];
```